# Variation on a cross tab/pivot table

Tags: php, mysql

I've been doing a lot of basic stuff with PHP, but have come up with a new twist on how I want to display some tabular data. I looked at the basic rules for constructing pivot/cross tab displays, but what I'm looking for seems to be a bit different. The primary data is stored in 1 table as (along with other fields):

- the station
- ID of ambulance at that station
- current status of ambulance (available, unavailable, out of service)

My present code outputs this...but looking for this:

http://www.countryhicksystems.com/upload/stack.jpg

[image]

I know we're to use PDO or MySQLi, but I set this up as a quick prototype.

```
//Log in, etc. code before this
$query = "SELECT * FROM $usertable WHERE $ems = $editID 
Order by equip_station, equip_descrp";

$result = mysql_query($query);

if($result)
{   
    echo "<table width=\"90%\"  border='1' align=\"left\" height=\"Auto\"  cellpadding=\"3\"       cellspacing=\"3\">
        <tr>
            <th width=\"65\"><div align=\"center\">Station</div></th>
            <th >Status</th>
            <th >As of Date</th>
            <th >Description</th>
        </tr>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td class=\"columnfont\">" .$row["$name"]."</div></td>";
        if ($row['equip_status'] == 'Available')
        {
            echo "<td class=\"green\">" .$row["$id"]."</div></td>";
        } 
        elseif ($row['equip_status'] == 'Unavailable')
        {
            echo "<td class=\"red\">" .$row["$id"]."</div></td>";
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "<td class=\"black\">" .$row["$id"]."</div></td>";
        }

        echo "<td class=\"cellfont\">" .$row["$availdate"]."</div></td>";
        echo "<td class=\"cellfont\">" .$row["$descr"]."</div></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
?>

</p>
</div>
```

How would I change my present code to display Station Ambulances across a row instead of down a column?

Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: Thanks for the status report on your current development efforts. Was there a question you intended to ask?

Comment: hint: if you want such format, you're going to have to put it inside an array first, then reformat it